# BackboneJS is performing fetch and failing, but everything in the response is entirely ok

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

The signal returns a `200`. The response text is accurate. Everything is OK. The server log returns no errors at all.

```
        @model.fetch(
          success: (model, resp) => 
            console.log 'sucess fetch'
          error: (error, object) =>
            console.log 'ya done messed up.'
            console.log error
            console.log object
        )
```

My object returns in its `.responseText` :

```
  responseText: "<div id='make_it_so'></div>↵<script>↵  $(function() {↵    window.router = new myApp.Routers.QuestionsRouter(↵    {↵      words: {"type":"stuff","word":"this","that":"what","booger":"me","that":"if","fancy":"boo","what":"sois","dog":"son"}  ↵    });↵    Backbone.history.start();↵  });↵</script>↵"
```

Headers are good. Everything is good. What possibly could be causing this? And how could I debug this further?

Comment: Your response is weird, it should just be a JSON object...

Comment: Ah sorry its just a piece of the response. The JSON object has a bunch of attributes and methods I thought was unecessary to post.

Comment: So... what is actually in your responseText? It would be interesting to have a look at it.

Comment: That is my responseText in full pasted above. Were the other parts of the object you wanted to see?

Comment: What my first comment meant is that this responseText is weird, it should only be a JSON object, while it's not. Not so sure how Backbone reacts with this, I'm searching.

Comment: Actually it's not even a Backbone problem, but a jQuery one, as Backbone proxies jQuery's ajax method. And I don't think jQuery likes your string while awaiting a JSON object.

Comment: Are you sure that the JSON returned is valid (for the entire response) using `JSON.parse`?

Comment: I think you both nailed it. @Loamhoof I'll accept that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For science, I did the test with jQuery, and here is jQuery's behavior when you don't feed it a JSON object:

```
status: 200 
statusText: "parsererror"
```

So that's what you had.